# HTML SELECT List showing description in columns for every OPTION

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I want to showin my HTML SELECT the values from the list on something like this for every OPTION

```
DESCRIPTION | TYPE
-------------------
CAR          TERRESTRIAL
AIRPLANE     AIR
SHIP         WATER
```

something like that, it is possible???
Thanks.

Comment: I don't believe so, no; but you could style a `dl` appropriately, maybe, or a regular list?

Answer (score 1):

Like David Thomas said. This is not really supported. But you can hack it. Make your font monospaced and space your option text object accordingly with non-breaking spaces.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Aq5LS/

To make it really nice, you need to implement your own combo box. Or use one like Ext JS's, http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.2a/examples/form/forum-search.html . Using Ext-JS just for this is definitely overkill, but it shows you what can be done.

Answer (score 0):

Your options for formatting text within a standard HTML select element are pretty limited, and I don't know of a reliable way to format option elements the way you requested.

One option would be to put the description in the title attribute of each option, which would show the description when a user hovers over an option (not sure about browser coverage here).

Another option would be to use a custom dropdown box control, which would give you much more liberty to format the options as you please. Searching for "jquery dropdown" should give you a good place to start.

Answer (score 0):

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/QZa7R/)

There's already something out there *sort of* like that.

```
<select>
  <optgroup label="Terestrial">
    <option value="Car">Car</option>
    <option value="Tank">Tank</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Air">
    <option value="Airplain">Airplain</option>
    <option value="Helicopter">Helicopter</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Water">
    <option value="Ship">Ship</option>
    <option value="Submarine">Submarine</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

Comment: From the question, it doesn't seem OP wants grouping, but headers and table like formatting.

Comment: Maybe, but based on his example, it seems like the "description" is really more like a "category", in which case using grouping would make more sense, not to mention being infinitely easier than trying to use a special widget.

Comment: @JuanMendes granted but I don't think there's much more out there :P (this option is also cross browser btw)

Comment: well i want to formatting more than sorting, something like showing a record on a TABLE per OPTION

Comment: @alexzm1 then no not really :( I would go look for a jQuery plugin to get the job done like Daniel Schaffer recommended

Comment: See my hacked answer! @Daniel Schaffer: It is true that Joseph's may solve the OP's problem, but it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @Juan: People ask questions on SO because they have a problem they need help solving. I've found that often, the best solution to a problem may not be directly answering the question as-is, but rather offering an alternative to what they're asking. Learning about better ways of solving problems, IMHO, is one of SO's greatest strengths.

Comment: @Daniel: Valid point. However, if I'm going to suggest something that is not an answer to the question, I prefer to make it a comment. It also bothers me when people do that to questions I ask, looks like I'm being treated like a noob and that they think they understand the problem better than I do. Yes, I know that many times people do understand the problem better than the person asking the question, but it's impolite to suggest that.

Comment: Well, I disagree on it being impolite, assuming of course the tone of the answer isn't. Getting answers suggesting something you consider to be obvious means there's an opportunity for you to clarify your question.

Comment: @Joseph, sorry for hijacking the comments on your answer... this discussion should probably be happening on meta.

Comment: @DanielSchaffer no problem! The discussion was quite fascinating.